# How to call a custom dialog box with Kotlin? Fails after converting java to kotlin

Tags: android, dialog, kotlin

Am trying to call a custom dialog box but the app crashes on this line:

```
cd.show()
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
val cd = CustomDialog(this, applicationContext)
    cd.show()
```

This is the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is
>   null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull,
>   parameter savedInstanceState

I followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android) and it works in java but fails after converting to kotlin

Comment: try making `savedInstanceState` nullable in parameter of `onCreate`

Comment: Please provide the CustomDialog code

Comment: I made savedInstanceState nullable and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your linked example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

In Kotlin, this should have become

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
```

Note the question mark, judging by your error message it's probably missing in your Kotlin code. The type `Bundle` does not accept `null` as a legal value (it's *non-nullable*) and adding a question mark to it broadens it to accept `null` values.

The activity can be started with no saved instance state, such as when first starting it after installation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass `context` when initializing `CustomDialog`.
For example, try this code:

```
val cd = CustomDialog(this@YourActivity) //Assuming you are initializing it in Activity.
cd.show()
```

Comment: This wouldn't be valid Kotlin code, you'd need `this@YourActivity` instead